# npm run build is giving me errors I'm not sure how to fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my first app and first time trying to deploy  and I'm facing an error I really don't know how to fix. This is what I'm getting when I run "npm run build"

```
PS C:\Users\julyj\Desktop\CODING\00 - Proton Media\BloCurate> npm run build

> proton-market@1.1.2 build
> next build

(node:11768) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at C:\Users\julyj\Desktop\CODING\00 - Proton Media\BloCurate\node_modules\postcss\package.json.
Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
Loaded env from C:\Users\julyj\Desktop\CODING\00 - Proton Media\BloCurate\.env.local
Failed to compile.

./components/AllAssets/index.tsx:32:8
Type error: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

  30 |   return (
  31 |     <ul>
> 32 |       {assets.map((result) => {
     |        ^
  33 |         const {
  34 |           collection: { name },
  35 |           data: { image },
info  - Creating an optimized production build .
PS C:\Users\julyj\Desktop\CODING\00 - Proton Media\BloCurate>
```

I tried looking up  **(node:11768) [DEP0148]** and there was a suggestion about changing a format under node modules from **"./"** to **"./*"** but that didn't fix the error. I'm not sure if the error is being caused by that or if it's the type error that's shown below.

Although it says **info - Creating an optimized production build** at the bottom, it doesn't create the build folder. Not sure if I need to post more information here but I'll gladly do so if requested in order to solve this issue.

Comment: The DeprecationWarning seems to actually just be a warning. The real error is "Type error: Object is possibly 'undefined'" in your index.tsx file. That is Typescript strict type checking you, and you should either assert to Typescript that `assets` will not be "undefined": `assets!.map(` or use optional chaining: `assets?.map(`

Comment: `DeprecationWarning` is, as the name suggests, just a warning. The `Type error` is  your problem. You should check for `null` / `undefined` with `?` or some `if` statement prior to the return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real error seems to be the `TypeError` in your TypeScript code. This can be fixed in two ways.

---

**1.** You can add the following code.

```js
assets!.map( // ...
```

This tells TypeScript that the object will *never* have the value of `undefined`. Therefore, it will infer that the type is `array`, instead of `array | undefined`.

---

**2.** You can add the following code.

```js
assets?.map( // ...
```

This code works both in JavaScript and TypeScript. The method used in this option is called *optional chaining*. It basically tells JavaScript/TypeScript that if `assets` is `undefined`, then it will not use the `map()` method, instead of throwing an error.

---

**Extra:** The `DeprecationWarning` can be safely ignored; it won't cause any issues with your deployment.